# How can I use an OpenVPN client confiugration file while keeping it encrypted in non-memory storage?

Tags: gnupg, openvpn

As a matter of practice, I'd like to keep my OpenVPN client configuration file encrypted in long-term storage. The only way I can find to pass the config data is by pointing openvpn to the file itself like `openvpn client.ovpn`. This means the file needs to be decrypted to the filesystem before I can use it.

Is there some way to pass the config values along the lines of the following?

`gpg -d client.ovpn.gpg | sudo openvpn -`

Answer (score 1):

You can create encrypted file in ram, mount it and keep it there.
Anyway if you setup correctly, you can have user `openvpn` as only user allowed access to file that is decrypted to ram.

If it's only user to read decrypted file, using chown, then nobody on your filesystem can read it, but if somebody's found your disk unencrypted he could.

If you keep it on mounted partition...
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cryptmount.8.html

That is encrypted whole time, just mounted unencrypted, even somebody having access to your hdd outside of computer wouldn't know your openvpn stuff.

Also this `gpg -d -a < client.openvpn.gpg | sudo openvpn --config /dev/stdin`